# Regex for mixed uppercase letters & numbers

Tags: regex, pcre

How can I match any string made of upper-case letters, sometimes mixed with numbers,
with a minimum of 4 characters, and no maximum. But I also want to avoid matching years (any 4-digit number starting with 1) e.g. 1912, 1830, 1998 when they are NOT part of a mixed letter/number string.

Sample text with strings to match in bold:

> Lorem ipsum dolor **11NFJVC** sit amet**FXUT0** consectetur **1976STK** adipisc**XWWFHH** year 1912.

Comment: what have you tried! Also specify the language/tool you are using! Regex implementation differs across languages/tools.

Comment: Might you have years that *don't* begin with 1 or are they all last millennium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this fits the bill:

```
(?<![A-Z\d])(?!1\d{3}\b)[A-Z\d]{4,}(?![A-Z\d])
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![A-Z\d]) # Make sure the previous character isn't uppercase alphanumeric
(?!          # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 1           # the digit 1
 \d{3}       # followed by three more digits
 (?![A-Z\d]) # where no other uppercase alphanumerics follow.
)            # (End of lookahead)
[A-Z\d]{4,}  # Match 4+ alphanumeric characters (uppercase letters only)
(?![A-Z\d])  # Make sure the next character isn't uppercase alphanumeric
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/cF1eY1).

Comment: It misses the uppercase letters & numbers when next to lowercase words.

Comment: Then I have misunderstood your requirements. So you want to match `XWWFHH` in your example above, is that correct? If so, you definitely need to tell us which regex engine you're using.

Comment: Yes I want to match `XWWFHH` and `FXUT0`, the regex engine I'm using is PCRE.

Comment: Matches years beginning 2 and up.

Comment: @Moob: Yes, that's what Diego specified it should do.

Answer (score 2):

Too late but this works:

```
(?!\d{4}\b)[A-Z\d]{4,}\b
```

http://regex101.com/r/tR8cZ7

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
\b(?!\d+\b)[A-Z\d]{4,}\b
```